# 2 ProcessEngines initialized. Explicitely initialise engine by calling ScenarioImpl(scenario, engine)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, camunda

I am getting following exception while executing Scenario.run(testProcessScenario).execute()
The issue is arising because there are two ProcessEngines at the time of this execution one is being loaded by contextLoad test in application

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"camunda.bpm.process-engine-name=account",
    // this is only needed if a SpringBootProcessApplication is used for the test
    "camunda.bpm.generate-unique-process-application-name=true",
    "spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=true",})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/application-test.properties")
class AccountServiceApplicationTests {

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {}
}
```

Second in memory process engine created via

```
@Deployment(resources = "account.bpmn")
public class AccountProcessServiceImplTest {


  @Rule
  @ClassRule
  public static final TestCoverageProcessEngineRule rule = TestCoverageProcessEngineRuleBuilder
      .create()
      .excludeProcessDefinitionKeys(SUB_PROCESS_ID)
      .assertClassCoverageAtLeast(1).build();

  @Mock
  private ProcessScenario testAccount;
  
  @Before
  public void defaultScenario() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ProcessExpressions.registerCallActivityMock(SUB_PROCESS_ID)
        .onExecutionAddVariable(SUB_PROCESS_EXECUTED, true).deploy(rule);
  }
  
  @Test
  public void shouldExecuteHappyPath() {
    Scenario.run(testAccount).startByKey(PROCESS_KEY, withVariables(VAR_ACCOUNT, "john"))
        .execute();

    verify(testAccount).hasFinished(END_EVENT_ACTIVITY);

    rule.addTestMethodCoverageAssertionMatcher("shouldExecuteHappyPath", greaterThanOrEqualTo(0.5));
  }
  }
```

because of these two process engines I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 ProcessEngines initialized. Explicitely initialise engine by calling ScenarioImpl(scenario, engine)

Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 ProcessEngines initialized. Explicitely initialise engine by calling ScenarioImpl(scenario, engine)
  at org.camunda.bpm.scenario.impl.ScenarioImpl.init(ScenarioImpl.java:85)
  at org.camunda.bpm.scenario.impl.ScenarioImpl.execute(ScenarioImpl.java:32)
  at org.camunda.bpm.scenario.impl.ProcessRunnerImpl.execute(ProcessRunnerImpl.java:119)
  at com.company.abc.bpm.process.impl.AccountProcessServiceImplTest.givenAccountIdWhenExecuteAccountProcessThenException(AccountProcessServiceImplTest.java:455)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
  at org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.ProcessEngineRule$1.evaluate(ProcessEngineRule.java:185)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
  at org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.ProcessEngineRule$1.evaluate(ProcessEngineRule.java:185)
  at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
  at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
  at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
  at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
  at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
  at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
  at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
  at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
  at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Kindly suggest.
Thanks

The version of the Camuda lib is 7.16.0.
The version of the SpringBoot is 2.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, spring boot support was added quite recently to the extension. Are you using the latest version? If so, it should work as described in the [example](https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-bpm-process-test-coverage/blob/master/examples/spring-starter/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/extension/process_test_coverage/examples/OrderProcessTest.java) (without using an extra class rule).

```
 @SpringBootTest
 @Import(CoverageTestConfiguration.class)
 public class OrderProcessTest { ... }
```

Comment: example link is expired.

Comment: Also, There is no extra class rule is used in springboottest class of OP question. I have the same issue. The unit test using process engine extension create another engine and conflict with the engine created by @springboottest in another test class.